# How to fix 'blank' iframe in Classic

Tags: salesforce

I placed the VF page with commandButton in Layout.
After pressing this button the frame with VF page become blank.

Here is console log state after button pressing:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005SQwQAM

You may also what to want to try to add this line to your code:
`add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-src 'self' https://salesforce.com;"`